# How to rebuild Opencv 3.1 after applying a patch, if Opencv was previously installed using an exe?

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I installed opencv 3.1 using the exe for windows. But there was a bug in matchers.cpp, for which I found a patch and applied it. Now how do I rebuild opencv so the affect of patch can take place?

Comment: You'll probably want to look at the [OpenCV documentation for building on Windows](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#building-the-library).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.